# How do I Change color of Placeholder text on search bar on toolbar using angular material?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

Need to change the color of the placeholder text. it is showing up dark. 
This should be done without using any CSS.

```
var themename = angular.module('themename', ['ngMaterial', 'ngAnimate'])
    .config(['$mdThemingProvider', function ($mdThemingProvider) {
        $mdThemingProvider.theme('default').primaryPalette('light-blue', {
            'default': '700',
            'hue-1': '500',
            'hue-2': '900',
            'hue-3': 'A700',
        }).accentPalette('orange',{
            'default': 'A200',
            'hue-1': 'A100',
            'hue-2': 'A400',
            'hue-3': 'A700',
            });

    }]);`
```

Comment: i think your are using Angular1.x for AngularJs(1.x) tag angularjs

Comment: Maybe this helpful;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205931/how-do-i-change-md-input-container-placeholder-color-using-css-in-angular-materi