# How to change text box placeholder color in Angular 6 Material

Tags: css, angular, material-design, angular-material2

**Angular 6 material code.**

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Input">
  </mat-form-field>
```

I wanted to change default color when input element get focused.

[image]

I have already tired this. [How do i change md-input-container placeholder color using css in angular material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41205931/how-do-i-change-md-input-container-placeholder-color-using-css-in-angular-materi/41205957)

nothing seems work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understand your question this css should work.

```
  .mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
      /*change color of label*/
      color: red !important;
  }

 .mat-form-field-underline {
   /*change color of underline*/
    background-color: blue !important;
 } 

.mat-form-field-ripple {
   /*change color of underline when focused*/
   background-color: yellow !important;;
 }
```

Hope it was useful.

Comment: yeah thanks..partially works..label color got changed. text box underline is not changing.

Comment: Do you want to underline also change color on select ?

Comment: underline color permanently appearing on text box. color should apply when it get focused only. pls check this https://xnpmjmxvknx.angular.stackblitz.io

Comment: It works as expected. but code worked only after i removed ::ng-deep prefix. i am using chrome. and i don't want initial  text box blue color underline. so i have only used 1, 3rd style alone.  i skipped 2nd style. Thank u so much.

Comment: Could u pls remove ::ng-deep. I have checked out in stackblitz also. see this https://stackblitz.com/angular/xnpmjmxvknx?file=styles.css

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179785/discussion-between-vignesh-r-and-nenad-radak).

Comment: Your code was NOT working for Angular 6, it needs the NG-deep and the !important tag:                                                                            
   ::ng-deep .mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {color: #3A4558 !important;}

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 7 and Material 7, this worked for me:

```
/* Placeholder overrides */
:host ::ng-deep input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7) !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7) !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7) !important;
}

:host ::ng-deep input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.7) !important;
}
```

For the underline, I used an outline styled input but you can just change the class used.

```
/* Appearance around each input/button to remove faded outline 
but put the dark hover back in */
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline {
    color: transparent !important;
}
::ng-deep .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.87) !important;
}
```

While I don't think this is the best way of doing it, especially using ::ng-deep, it's the only thing that works right now for a specific component, for me.